# I define a field as varchar(30) but I can insert character only 28

Tags: sql-server, varchar

I don't understand I already define size of character as `VARCHAR(30)` and I try to insert data via web page = `STIFF COMP,R FR DOOR SKIN CTR`
but it can't

> Error string or binary data would be truncated

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: did you include white spaces when counting the char count ?...if not, that might be your problem.

Comment: "STIFF COMP,R FR DOOR SKIN CTR" 
I try to input this data but it can't but when I delete 1 character  "STIFF COMP,R FR DOOR SKIN CT" It can insert to db

Comment: Can you please format the question and add some more info?

Comment: Try to check the length with `DATALENGTH()` rather than `LEN()`. `LEN` will ignore trailing spaces... You might use `LTRIM(RTRIM(YourString))` to cut it short...

Comment: Have you check the input string? Will it have some other special character after return from web page?

Comment: Check for nbsp (non breaking space) = char(160) and replace with ''. Try REPLACE(Your_Column, NCHAR(0x00A0), '')

Comment: I double check again it no space because it read data from .txt file "STIFF COMP,R FR DOOR SKIN CTR"

Comment: Another possibility is that there's a trigger, computed column or indexed view on this table and it's within the definition/operation of those features that the truncation error is occurring.

Comment: You should test how your txt file is parsed. I assume it's not what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

If you create your column correctly, then it should work well

Let's see the simple example below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_1](
    [stringTest] [varchar](30) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Just a simple `Table_1` with 1 row `[stringTest]` type `[varchar](30)`

Then I insert your string `insert into Table_1(stringTest) values('STIFF COMP,R FR DOOR SKIN CTR')`

It's working fine, so just a confirm: - your original text is fitted.
So other concern is:

1. You set up database wrongly (check my above simple table)
2. You use an application (asp.net per-harp) to add the value in. So you may check in debug mode to see the correct value (may be it's formatted or encoded, since i saw a comma `,` in your string)